# Пожалуйста, помогите со знаками препинания

Tags: пунктуация

Объясните постановку знаков препинания:

Было очень тяжело: постоянные упрёки, неуместные обиды и ссоры - и это во время  начала моей болезни;

Меня никто не смог понять НИКТО, кроме моего друга и родителей.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что д/з.

Answer (score 2):

(1) Было очень тяжело: постоянные **упрёки**, неуместные **обиды и ссоры** – и (всё) **это** во время начала моей болезни.

БСП, второе предложение раскрывает содержание первого. Второе предложение эллиптического типа (однородный ряд подлежащих – обстоятельство времени), после однородного ряда  ставится тире, далее присоединительный союз И и указательное слово ЭТО со значением обобщения.

(2) Меня никто не смог понять – никто, кроме моего друга и родителей. Присоединительная конструкция, обособление с помощью тире.

Comment: Не согласны с behemothus?

Comment: Оба предложения имеют нестандартную конструкцию, такие примеры вряд ли можно найти  в ПАС, поэтому не похоже на домашнее задание. Предложенный вариант разбора, скорее всего, не единственный, может быть, кто-нибудь озвучит другое решение.

Comment: Хорошо. Понятно.